# Capitalising certain names mid string

Tags: vb.net

The current code being used is below this code looks for O' Mac and Mc and if it finds it in the string it Capitalizes the first letter after it.
We have had the issue where for example a name like Macey is also being capitalised to MaCey. I am looking for some help on how to combat this. I know it will most likely be getting the code to check that the string is greater than 2 characters after the Mc / Mac / O'.

Any help would be much appreciated as am new to coding.

```
Pos = InStr(Trim(lName), " ")
        If Pos > 0 Then
            Return CapitaliseName(Trim(Left(lName, Pos))) & " " & CapitaliseName(Mid(lName, Pos + 1))
            Exit Function
        End If

        lName = LCase(Trim(lName))

        Pos = InStr(lName, "mac")
        If Pos > 0 Then Len = 3
        If Pos = 0 Then
            Pos = InStr(lName, "mc")
            Len = 2
        End If
        If Pos = 0 Then
            Pos = InStr(lName, "o'")
            Len = 2
        End If

        If Pos = 0 Then
            CapitaliseName = StrConv(lName, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
        Else
            CapitaliseName = StrConv(Left(lName, Pos - 1), VbStrConv.ProperCase) &
                            StrConv(Mid(lName, Pos, Len), VbStrConv.ProperCase) &
                            StrConv(Mid(lName, Pos + Len), VbStrConv.ProperCase)
        End If
```

Comment: I'd rather expect `MacEy` as the undesired output if `Macmillan` correctly yields `MacMillan`.

Comment: some approches over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472928/mcdonalds-to-propercase-in-c-sharp

Comment: what would be your output for  `Mcgrath` , `Macgrath` and `Mcey` ?