# format name prefixes (mcdonald, o'brien, etc)

Tags: .net, string

Had a search around and can't find anything that will easily and accurately (as much as possible anyway) look at names and capitalise where appropriate.

I.e. If last name is 'smith' make it 'Smith'. If 'mcdonald' make it 'McDonald'. If "o'brien" make it "O'Brien", etc.

This topic (old) [mcdonalds to ProperCase in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472928/mcdonalds-to-propercase-in-c-sharp) has some discussion. Given this was 9 years ago, I'm wondering if a nice solution has been thought up?

Thanks!

Comment: If it had, it most likely would have been added as an additional answer to that post. What's wrong with the solutions there?

Comment: You have no idea what can of worms you've opened. Names are **HARD**. You're really better off getting a list of the top 10000 or so last names, doing a case insensitive compare, and replacing with the correct version from your list when you have a match, or leave it alone if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, use a name dictionary to find the name. Then correct the casing. Some programmer friendly ones:

https://github.com/dominictarr/random-name/blob/master/first-names.txt

https://github.com/davidsbatista/lexicons

[Raw list of person names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803628/raw-list-of-person-names)

Warning none of them seem to have my name (Samy). So they are clearly missing at least one important name.